# JQuery, Select Case statements with functions, and getting it all working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, select

Have run into an issue that I have tried working through for the past day or two and can't seem to figure out.

The title doesn't do the question justice - it's a bit more complex/harder to explain.

So I have this code for a custom DropSearch:

```
<% Select Case dtype%>
<% Case "postbasic"%>
<div class="SearchOverallbox" style="<%= sstyle %>">
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" class="SearchBoxstyle InputClass" runat="server" onkeyup="RefreshUpdatePanel();" AutoCompleteType="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ListBox ID="SearchList" class="SearchListstyle DropDownClass" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" onclick="listclick();" Style="display: none;"></asp:ListBox>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RefreshUpdatePanel() {
        if ($('#<%=SearchBox.ClientID%>').val() !== "") {
            $('#<%=SearchList.ClientID%>').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Controls/ServerCalls.aspx/SearchDrop",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    SearchVal: $("#<%=SearchBox.ClientID%>").val(),
                    Type: "<%=query %>"
                }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {

                    var htmlSelect = document.getElementById('<%=SearchList.ClientID%>');
                    if (msg.d.length > 0) {
                        htmlSelect.innerHTML = msg.d;
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error has occurred during processing your request.");
                }
            })
            }
            else {
                $('#<%=SearchList.ClientID%>').hide();
            $('#<%=SearchList.ClientID%>').empty();

        }
    }

    function listclick() {
        $("#<%=SearchBox.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=SearchList.ClientID%> :selected").text());
        document.getElementById('<%=SearchList.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "";
        $('#<%=SearchList.ClientID%>').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Now I have multiple textboxes that have 'postbasic' as the aforementioned 'dtype'.

So each of my controls fills this code in at runtime perfectly, and debugging this in Chrome/IE shows that each control has this script attached to it, with each definition as it should be.

However, when I go to the page and try to test this, it skips to the last control with this script attached to it, and runs through it - even if I'm writing in a textbox control at the very top.

eg. If I fill out description at the top, it checks if supplier number at the very bottom has any text in it, and if there is anything, it shows the DropList attached to the supplier number control, rather than in the description text box.

Any help would be appreciated. Further clarification is available if need be.

Kind regards,

Dee.

Comment: i think your updated code is fine. only some stuff: change CurrentTextBox to currentTextBox so you know it's a var, and not a class. change `bind` to `on` (https://api.jquery.com/bind/). You don't need to `$("#" + CurrentListBox + "")`, just `$("#" + CurrentListBox)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a workaround that works for me. It's a bit untidy, but with a little more work I'll get it nice and neat, but functionality was what I was after and I've got it. Also, it lets me get rid of each separate case for each of the textboxes, so I've cleared out about 400 lines of excess code.

Code:

```
  <script>
    $('.SearchOverallbox').on('keyup', function(){
        var CurrentTextBox = $('*:focus').attr('id');
        var CurrentListBox = CurrentTextBox.replace("SearchBox", "SearchList")

        var splitFirstUS = CurrentTextBox.indexOf("_", 0)
        var splitLastUS = CurrentTextBox.lastIndexOf("_")
        var queryString = CurrentTextBox.substring(splitFirstUS+1, splitLastUS)

        if(CurrentTextBox.length > 1){
            $("#" + CurrentListBox).show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Controls/ServerCalls.aspx/SearchDrop",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    SearchVal: $("#" + CurrentTextBox).val(),
                    Type: queryString
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

                var htmlSelect = document.getElementById(CurrentListBox);
                if (msg.d.length > 0) {
                    htmlSelect.innerHTML = msg.d;
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An error has occurred during processing your request.");
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        $("#" + CurrentListBox).hide();
        $("#" + CurrentListBox).empty();

    }
});
```

Hope this helps anyone in the same boat as I was (although I doubt it!).

Dee.